# Why am I getting a high address when I use kmalloc with GFP_DMA in Linux?

Tags: linux, opensuse, dma, kmalloc

I am writing a device driver for a DMA device in Linux.  In [Linux Device Drivers, Chapter 15](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf), it says:

> For devices with this kind of limitation, memory should be allocated
>   from the DMA zone by adding the GFP_DMA flag to the kmalloc or
>   get_free_pages call. When this flag is present, only memory that can
>   be addressed with 24 bits is allocated. Alternatively, you can use the
>   generic DMA layer (which we discuss shortly) to allocate buffers that
>   work around your device’s limitations

I am calling `kmalloc` like this:

```
physical_pointer0 = kmalloc(number_of_bytes, GFP_DMA);
```

and printing the result like this:

```
  printk(KERN_INFO "pinmem:pinmen_write kmalloc succeeded.  pointer is %p, buffer size is %d\n", physical_pointer0, (unsigned)number_of_bytes);
```

And this is what I see:

```
Sep  9 00:29:45 nfellman_lnx kernel: [  112.161744] pinmem:pinmen_write kmalloc succeeded.  pointer is ffff880000180000, buffer size is 320800
```

How can I be getting a pointer to `0xffff880000180000`, which doesn't fit in 24 bits, if I used GFP_DMA?

Could it be that this is not the physical address of my block of memory?  If not (which would mean I'm completely misunderstanding `kmalloc`), how can I get its physical address?

---

I am working in OpenSuse 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this appears to be that `kmalloc` doesn't in fact return a physical pointer, but rather a linear pointer, that I must convert to physical with `virt_to_phys`.

Thanks to [Alex Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121332/alex-brown) for providing the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12346036/1084).