# How can kmalloc return a physical address greater than the size of the physical address?

Tags: linux, memory-management, kmalloc

I am allocating a block of memory with `kmalloc` in a device driver in Linux.  The address that I get is `0xffff880000180000`.  I am using an IvyBridge processor with a 46-bit physical address space.  That means that the CPU doesn't have more than 46 addressing pins, so it can't access any address above `0x00003fffffffffff`.  The address I'm getting is obviously greater than that, as it has bit 47 set.

Assuming that `kmalloc` returns a physical pointer (that is, a pointer where the virtual, linear and physical addresses are the same), how can I be getting such an address, if it's not accessible by the CPU?

---

This question is related to "[Why am I getting a high address when I use kmalloc with GFP_DMA in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337914/why-am-i-getting-a-high-address-when-i-use-kmalloc-with-gfp-dma-in-linux)".  However, it is not identical.  This question is about the physical addresses `kmalloc` returns in general, whereas the linked question is about use of `GFP_DMA` and its relationship to the returned address.

Comment: The physical address space has usually both small and big addresses, so 0xffff880000180000 could be inside it.

Comment: But the CPU doesn't have that many address bits.  How can it access such high bits if it doesn't have the full 64 bits, or even the canonical 48?

Comment: I think that x86-64 requires that a bunch of most significant bits of the address are all 0 or all 1.

Comment: right, bits 63:48 must all be the same, but that goes for virtual and linear addresses, not (to the best of my knowledge) for physical addresses.

Comment: Assuming that kmalloc returns a physical pointer? It always give virtual address! use `virt_to_phys`.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ kmalloc always return virtual memory pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly not a physical address but a linear or virtual address, and is in 'canonical form' where the value of bit 47 is 'sign extended' up to bit 63.

Comment: So how can I get the physical address for use by my device?

Comment: There are plenty of other questions on stackoverflow dealing with that issue.  Go search!  Have fun!